# Content must have a ListView whose id attribute is

Tags: android

I have setup chart engine it worked fine and after try to add one more graph to chart, I  got following error message on log cat. There is no list in the code though it is extendds from listactivity.

what is the wrong with the code.

```
package org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo;

import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class ChartDemo extends ListActivity {
     private GraphicalView mChart;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.xy_chart);
            openChart();
        }

        private void openChart(){

            int count = 5;
            Date[] dt = new Date[5];
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, i+1);
                dt[i] = gc.getTime();
            }

            int[] visits = { 2000,2500,2700,2100,2800};
            int[] views = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 3200};
            int[] views3 = {2100, 2740, 2100, 2900, 3100};
            // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
            TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("Visits");

            // Creating TimeSeries for Views
            TimeSeries viewsSeries = new TimeSeries("Views");
            TimeSeries viewsSeries3 = new TimeSeries("Views3");

            // Adding data to Visits and Views Series
            for(int i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
                visitsSeries.add(dt[i], visits[i]);
                viewsSeries.add(dt[i],views[i]);
                viewsSeries3.add(dt[i],views3[i]);
            }

            // Creating a dataset to hold each series
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

            // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
            dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

            // Adding Visits Series to dataset
            dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries);
            dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries3);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer3 to customize viewsSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits vs Views Chart");
            multiRenderer.setXTitle("Days");
            multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
            multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

            // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer
            // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
            // should be same
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer3);
            // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
            LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

            // Creating a Time Chart
            mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");

            multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
            multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

            // Setting a click event listener for the graph
            mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

                    if (seriesSelection != null) {
                        int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                        String selectedSeries="Visits";
                        if(seriesIndex==0)
                            selectedSeries = "Visits";
                        else
                            selectedSeries = "Views";

                        // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                        long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                        Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                        String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                        // Getting the y value
                        int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                        // Displaying Toast Message
                        Toast.makeText(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            selectedSeries + " on "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
                chartContainer.addView(mChart);
        }

//      @Override
//      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//          getMenuInflater().inflate(R., menu);
//          return true;
//      }
}
```

Logcat:

```
  03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo/org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.ChartDemo}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.ChartDemo.onCreate(ChartDemo.java:47)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-19 20:25:16.690: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  ... 11 more
```

here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_tv_title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your XML as well.

Comment: According to the stack trace, it is crashing on line 45 of ChartDemo.java, which it states as being in the onCreate function. However, in the code you've posted line 45 isn't in onCreate. Is this definitely the code that is crashing? Are there more lines you've removed for simplicity? Could you highlight line 45?

Comment: I have updated the code again.please check!

Comment: The updated logcat puts the crash at line 47 - could you highlight that line please? the answer below is correct: To extend ListView your layout (R.layout.xy_chart) must have a ListView in it with id `list`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using `ListActivity` with a custom layout, your layout must contain a `ListView` with the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`